# 24 AC to 32 DC. How?

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor, bridge-rectifier

I encountered the following problem: inside an equipment, an added PCB needs **32** V **DC** and in that enclosure, only **24** V **AC** is accessible. In order to get 32 V DC from that 24 V AC, someone put a bride rectifier and a **6800 uf** (68 V) electrolytic capacitor in parallel to the load. Doing this, 32 V DC were obtained.

Now, my questions are:

1. How did he calculate the value of the capacitor in order to boost the voltage to *32 V DC* from *24 V DC* (after rectification)?
2. I don't have an oscilloscope to see the waveform after rectification and filtration but, is there a better way to obtain 32 DC from 24 AC regarding the output waveform?

   If you know good tutorials in order to understand these principles better, please let me know.

   Your responses will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: "is there a better way"? There are other ways, but "better" depends on requirements that you will need to specify.

Comment: Keep in mind that such a scheme will impose a specific relationship between the AC and DC voltages, which may complicate any signalling between the subcircuits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How did he calculate the value of the capacitor in order to boost the voltage to 32 V DC from 24 V DC (after rectification)?

If the input is really 24**VAC**, after rectification the **DC** peak voltage at the capacitor will be given by:

$$V_{cap} = 14VAC \cdot \sqrt2 - 2\cdot (V_{DIODE})\approx 32VDC$$

Provided that the load connected to the capacitor does not draw too much power, down to the point where it would considerably discharge, the average output voltage would be slightly lower than 32VDC.

The capacitor value depends on the load, the allowed voltage drop between cycles, and the line frequency according to the following.

$$C\ge\dfrac{P_{max}\left(\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{\arcsin\left(\dfrac{V_{min}}{V_{peak}}\right)}{\pi}\right)}{(V_{peak}^2-V_{min}^2)\cdot f_{line}}$$

Where:

\$V_{min}\$ is the minimum allowed voltage during discharge;

\$V_{peak}\$ is the peak voltage across the capacitor (e.g. 32VDC);

\$f_{line}\$ is the frequency of the input AC voltage (e.g. 60Hz);

> I don't have an oscilloscope to see the waveform after rectification and filtration but, is there a better way to obtain 32 DC from 24 AC regarding the output waveform?

If by that you mean to measure the voltage, you can simply measure the RMS voltage across the capacitor. It should give something close to 32VDC.

**EDIT#1**

The equation proposed above assumes that no input cycles are skipped.

**EDIT#2**

Just for clarification, here is the derivation. Assume thatthe voltage across the capacitor is the following:

[image: waveform]

The capacitor formula is given by:

$$\Delta I = C \dfrac{dV}{dt}$$

By replacing \$\Delta I\$ with \$\dfrac{P}{\Delta V}\$ and integrating the equation, the follwing is obtained:

$$P\cdot t = \dfrac{C}{2} \cdot \left(V_{peak}^2 - V_{min}^2\right)$$

where \$t=t_1 + t_2\$ in the above picture.

Since \$t_1\$ is a quarter of period, its radian equivalent is given by:

$$t_1 = \dfrac{2\pi}{4}\cdot \dfrac{1}{f}=\dfrac{\pi}{2\cdot f_{line}}$$

\$t_2\$ on the other hand can be calculated through the following way. It it is not so clear to see it, assume for the moment that \$V_{peak} = V_{min}\$ in the above image, it would mean that \$t_2=\dfrac{\pi}{2}(90°)\$. This in turn could be used to reverse calculate and check the amplitude ratio of both voltages according to:

$$\arcsin\left( \dfrac{V_{min}}{V_{peak}} \right)=\arcsin(1)=90°$$

That means that the following holds true

$$t_2 = \arcsin\left(\dfrac{V_{min}}{V_{peak}}\right)\cdot \dfrac{1}{f_{line}} $$

Rearranging everything you end up with the formula shown in the original answer.

Comment: And the capacitance can be calculated by how much current the load consumes, and how much voltage drop from the peak rectified value it can tolerate.

Comment: Can you send me some more resources (e.g. a link from a blog) in order to understand it in more detail please?

Comment: What part exactly is not so clear?

Comment: I don't understand why is there an arcsin function.

Comment: I am gonna edit my answer to put more details.

Comment: @tibi10 I hope now it is clear.

Comment: @vtolentino thank you for your effort.